# jQuery while loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to figure out how to loop through elements with the same class and animate them one at a time.  I figured this while loop would work but I can't understand why it won't.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var index = 0;
    var images = $('.image');

    while (index < images.length) {
        var image = images[index];
        image.animate({
            opacity: "1"
        }, 1000, function() {
            index++;
        });
    };
});
```

Heres the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/conadrisca/w4cgctyk/)

Comment: Try images.width() instead in your if statement

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need a `;` at the end of a `while` block.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a simple implementation of what @Evert [brilliantly explains in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482239/597441).

Citing their answer here

> index++ is called in a callback that's executed after the animation.
>   The animation would only start after this script has stopped
>   executing.
>
> Because of this, index++ never gets executed and the loop never ends.
>
> You need to rewrite this as a recursive function. The event handler
>   that now calls index++ actually needs to be responsible for setting up
>   the next animation.

Implementation can be something like this

```
var index = 0;
var images = $('.image');
animate(images);

function animate() {
    var image = images.eq(index);
    image.animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, 1000, function () {
        index++;
        animate();
    });
}
```

Demo **https://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/w4cgctyk/2/**

Comment: Well done =) Should combine your example and my explanation :P

Comment: Thank you this was exactly what I was looking to accomplish.

Comment: @Evert: That is exactly what I was about to do

Answer (score 8):

`index++` is called in a callback that's executed *after* the animation. The animation would only start *after* this script has stopped executing.

Because of this, `index++` never gets executed and the loop never ends.

You need to rewrite this as a recursive function. The event handler that now calls `index++` actually needs to be responsible for setting up the next animation.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up for me.  You and Dhiraj helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

There's also a jQuery .each function, used like this:

```
$('.class').each(function() {
 $(this).animate(); 
});
```

Where this is the next item with that class

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that OP wants to animated the images one at a time.

Comment: @Evert I see. The while loop will not animate the next element until the previous one has animated? Thank you for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is going wrong at `index++;` You should have a recursive function. You need to increment the value of `index` within the recursive function.

```
function YourRecusiveFunction() {
    var image = images.eq(index);
    image.animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, 1000, function () {
        index++;
        YourRecusiveFunction();
    });
}
```

Call `YourRecusiveFunction()` once the document is ready.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use the jQuery `each` function?

```
var images = $('.image');

$.each(images,function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity:"1"
    }, 1000, function(){
        index++;
    });
 });
```

Comment: This doesn't address the fact that OP wants to animated the images one at a time.